# Boot Failed: Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems

Tags: boot, 16.04

I suddenly got my desktop machine to fail booting with no obvious reason. I haven't made any significant changes/updates since the last shutdown. Here is what happens:

Normal boot sequence throws me off to tty1. After successful login:

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrader-motd: 31: /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrader-motd: cannot create /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrader-available: Read-only file system
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: 33: cannot create /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: Read-only file system

Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS! (<kernel_version>)

0 packages can be updated

0 updates are security updates

*** /dev/sda2 should be checked for errors ***


user@user:^$ _
```

*Note: Switching to tty7 doesn't work. The screen blanks a little and then that's it*

Going through recovery mode and running fsck gives:

[image: recovery_mode_fsck]

Issuing the command shown (systemctl ...) through a root shell gives:

[image: command_issued]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets first check your file system for errors.

For Ubuntu 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose <kbd>Advanced Options</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Recovery mode</kbd>
- choose <kbd>Root access</kbd>
- at the `#` prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For Ubuntu 18.04 or newer... (or if the above steps don't work for you)...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: You can't force a check while any partition is mounted. I unmounted / then forced a check. Turns out there were a couple of orphaned nodes need to be fixed and then boot resumed flawlessly. Thank you. _On a side note: do you think that preventing fsck to do periodic checks might have caused the issue ?_

Comment: You don't want to disable fsck checks. Cheers, Al

Comment: @egy It's possible.  It's happened to me before.

Answer (score 15):

For me, this problem appeared after I installed a backup with wrong/old fstab UUIDs. Search for the right UUIDs with `sudo blkid` and update the `/etc/fstab` file accordingly.

Comment: I have the correct UUIDs in fstab, Still my system gives this error (It boots fine though)

Comment: @snickers2k worked fine for me, thank you a lot

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my glitchy Raspberry Pi that was displaying the same error message on boot

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue, the reason is I am practising something on beaglebone black board, for some reason kernel is crashing there due to rootfs.

So I thought of doing some changes in /etc/fstab file on SDCard(using for boot on Embedded target board).

But unintentionally, I changed entry in host machine's /etc/fstab file.
Below is the file after changes.

**/etc/fstab**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCAbB.png

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
/dev/mmcblk0p2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=3da12936-818f-48e9-b50c-3d6f2892d332 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=48DC-BBA7  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=2a861f0b-d5d1-4624-88b6-fea51e93427f none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I have read multiple ways on google and nothing is resolved, so I started understanding

- how rootfs is mounted
- from it is taking it's configuration while
- booting what if rootfs throws error & which configuration settings changes it's mounting style(readonly OR readwrite)

Before that, I need atleast a terminal to work, I am able to get terminal with "ALT + F3" keyboard shortcut.

Then I tried some editing on /etc/fstab file, which I am unable to it.
Because, right now rootfs is mounted with readonly access.
I need to change it as readwrite access to some modifications here.

Then, I checked all mount points with command

> **cat /proc/mounts**

for me, it's showing `"ro"` for `"/"` partition.

Below command will change the permissions to readwrite

`mount -o remount/rw <rootpartion Identifier> <rootpartition>`

to get **rootpartion Identifier**, use lsblk

```
nvme0n1     259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 375.8G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0     1G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0  95.4G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                     /
└─nvme0n1p6 259:6    0   4.6G  0 part [SWAP]
waageesh@waageesh-Aspire-A715-75G:~$
```

it's nvme0n1p5 for me, so above command will changes to
`sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/nvme0n1p5 /`

Now I tried editing /etc/fstab file, but I still don't know the flow and what are the options saying in /etc/fstab file.

After some research, I got some points

- on system bootup, GRUB will use `/etc/default/grub` file to generate `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file
- GRUB will see configuration settings in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. I can see the entry with `ro` access as `linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic root=UUID=3da12936-818f-48e9-b50c-3d6f2892d332 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff`. so it's taking setting from /etc/fstab file.
- `/dev/mmcblk0p2 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1` line is culprit in mycase, options given for that filesystem entry are **errors=remount-ro**
- GRUB will try to mount all filesystem as per entries(each line in /etc/fstab is one entry per filesystem) in the same order defined.
- If any error is there in mounting, it will check for options. My case, options are **errors=remount-ro**, which means try to remount with "ro" access on error
- I got error, because that partion(/dev/mmcblk0p2) is not valid, and it's on SDCard, but not on actual HOST machine.

In some machines, instead of filesystem/partition name, UUID is given, I do have already a line with UUID of root partition(/) as 2nd line. I confirmed
it using `sudo blkid`

```
waageesh@waageesh-Aspire-A715-75G:~$ cat /etc/fstab | grep "3da12936-818f-48e9-b50c-3d6f2892d332"
UUID=3da12936-818f-48e9-b50c-3d6f2892d332 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
waageesh@waageesh-Aspire-A715-75G:~$ cat /etc/fstab | grep /dev/nvme0n1p5
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
waageesh@waageesh-Aspire-A715-75G:~$
```

I just deleted invalid entry for filesystem, which doesn't even exist on machine, saved and closed the file.
Did Reboot the machine & it's working fine.