# Ubuntu 20.04 unable to load, stuck @Ubuntu screen

Tags: boot, mount

NEED HELP ASAP!!!!

I am new to Ubuntu and used it for over 1.5 months now. I was going through a YT video to see 50 must things to do after installing Ubuntu 20.04 I made some changes to /etc/fstab to reduce SSD writes. After I reboot my system these errors pop up on the screen and further my screen is stuck with DELL and Ubuntu on it. I am getting these errors...

[FAILED] Failed to start **Remount Root** and **Kernel File systems.**

[FAILED] Failed to activate **swap** /swapfile.
[DEPEND] Dependancy failed for **Swap**.

I have tried many methods including

I) Grub menu > Advanced options for Ubuntu > Recovery mode > fsck, dpkg, updating grub menu. None of them have changed what has happened to my pc.

II) I have also tried editing the command in grub menu by adding "nomodset" command.

III) I aslo tried both the solutions mentioned in here
[Boot Failed: Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822887/boot-failed-failed-to-start-remount-root-and-kernel-file-systems). but in vain.

I am attaching pictures and responses of code I got to all these options.
Any help is appreciated.

Link to the pics:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Z1kLySIK_PQN5foeEVZe1JVakTJJPQBv?usp=sharing

Comment: The obvious solution is to undo the changes that you made to /etc/fstab. Boot to Recovery Mode, remount / as r/w with `mount -o remount,rw /`, then edit /etc/fstab and remove your changes `pico /etc/fstab` and save the file, then `reboot`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please elaborate the process from after the recovery mode. I tried writing these commands on root option but nothing really happened.

Comment: Please see my answer. Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply and support

Comment: I have done it and it worked out, but still I wasn't able to boot into Ubuntu, I eventually reinstalled the whole software with 22.04 Thanks for your support and effort

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you made a very common newbie error... you followed a YouTube video that suggested that you make changes to a very important system file. **Never** follow those kind of instructions if you're not fully aware of the implications of those changes. You ended up with a non-bootable system.

Boot to the GRUB menu, choose **Additional Options**, then choose **Recovery Mode**, then choose **ROOT prompt**. You should be at the # prompt.

In this mode, the disk is in read-only mode, so we have to change that to read/write mode, with this command...

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then we edit /etc/fstab and undo the changes that you made that caused the current problem... use arrow keys to move around in the file, use control-o to save the changes, use control-x to exit the editor...

```
sudo pico /etc/fstab
```

Then we reboot...

```
reboot
```

**Update #1:**

Ended up reinstalling Ubuntu.